# XMLPay Schema: 2001 Spec?

Tags: xml, schema

I'm working on a Java integration with Payflow for performing credit card authorizations.  Submitting XML requests would be easiest for us, so I've been focusing on the XMLPay schema found in the XMLPay Developer's Guide (https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/developer/docs/pdf/pp_payflowpro_xmlpay_guide.pdf).

The schema in this XML document uses the 1999 spec.  Does anyone know if Payflow has made a schema available that uses the 2001 schema spec?  Thank you in advance for any assistance.  I'm having trouble validating the 1999 spec and generating POJOs.